# How to adjust navigationBarTitle and Label Text alignment in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I just learned swiftUI and I got little trouble. I want to make navigationBarTitle and title headline alignment like this:

[Image 1: I want to make my view like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGYIl.png)

I have tried to make like below but it does not work:

```
struct HeaderView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Image("kante_training_champions_league")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 370, height: 150)
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
            Text("KANTE: NEW PLAYERS DON’T SEEM NEW")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .frame(width: 370)
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Chelsea FC")
    }
  }
}
```

From my code above, I got a view like this:

[Image 2: I got a view like this from my code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SBN8.png)

Could someone help me how to get a view like I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leading alignment

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {     // << here !!

        // ... no changes in image

        Text("KANTE: NEW PLAYERS DON’T SEEM NEW")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .padding(.leading)                    // << here !!
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add alignment to StackView. You can change alignment to **.leading**, **.trailing** or **.center**. It is centered by default thats why you are having the label in center.

```
var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {    
    // Your Code
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.frame(width: 370)` and use  `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` so that the text takes the whole width of its parent.

```
        VStack {
            Image("kante_training_champions_league")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 370, height: 150)
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
            Text("KANTE: NEW PLAYERS DON’T SEEM NEW")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            Spacer()
        }
```